# Как разделить квадрат вписанный в круг на несколько точек, зная только радиус круга и координаты центра круга?

Tags: python, математика

мне нужно разделить сторону вписанного в окружность квадрата на определенное количество точек(равномерно) и сохранить их координаты, зная радиус окружности, центральную точку окружности и кол-во точек. Желательно на python3.

У меня есть вариант для просто круга без квадрата:

`for i in range(0, int(count_points or 1) + 1):
y = round((np.sin(i * 6.28 / float(count_points) or 1) * (float(objective_radius)) + float(objective_y)), 3)
x = round((np.cos(i * 6.28 / float(count_points) or 1) * (float(objective_radius)) + float(objective_x)), 3`

Comment: Квадрат состоит из несчетного множества точек. Разделить его даже на счетное количество точек и то не получится :) Сформулируйте свою задачу нормальным математическим языком, pls...

Comment: Понятнее после изменения не стало... Опишите внятно, что Вам нужно сделать?

Comment: Мне нужно разделить квадрат на условно 10 точек, которые находятся на одинаковом расстоянии друг от друга

Comment: Во-первых, нельзя разделить квадрат на точки, как Вам выше Harry написал. Во вторых, если Вам нужно найти 10 точек на квадрате на равном расстоянии друг от друга, то, в отличии от круга,  появляется вопрос - что считать равным расстоянием?

Comment: И сторону квадрата - тоже нельзя разделить на точки, по тем же причинам, что и квадрат. Чтобы получить более-менее внятный ответ, нужно сначала правильно задать вопрос.

Comment: Еще решение задачи зависит от того, как ориентирован квадрат, вписанный в круг.

Comment: на плоскости я могу представить максимально 3 точки, которые находятся на одинаковом расстоянии друг от друга. Они образуют равносторонний треугольник. Непонятно, о каких 10 точках вы говорите. Сформулируйте задачу, а лучше скопируйте текст задачи в вопрос, своими словами у вас не получается.

Comment: равномерно  по периметру квадрата или по углу?